# Generate unique user id in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, format

I am developing an app using Laravel which will have a functionality to register user. 
I want to provide customized unique id to every user (ie: User_id = SM129).
Userid will have following features:
1) User id will be auto-generated while registering. 
2) Auto-generated user id should be Check to a database for its uniqueness.

Currently, I am using following code to generated unique user id based on current date. but there is a chance of duplicity on a username with this. Please help

```
<?php
//creates a unique id for user id 
echo "<br>";
$day = date('D');
$month = date('F');
$year = date('Y');
$fmonth = substr($month, 0, 1);
$fyear = substr($year, 2, 2);
$fday = substr($day, 0, 1);
$uniq = rand();
$funiq = substr($uniq, 0, 2);
$funiq1 = substr($uniq, 0, 1);
$joint=  'ST'.$fmonth.$fday.$funiq1.$fyear.$funiq ;
?>

<input type="text" name="username" value = "<?php echo $joint; ?>">
```

Comment: should be something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_mt_rand.asp) but you need to create a query that will check if the number already exists in the database

Comment: This is also a way but convinced with UUID much more. thank you Hungrykoala for the answer.

Comment: How about using an auto-incrementing and unique int field in your database?

Comment: Like a default id field? this function will be fine if it allow me to attach some strings within it. like: Sep100 , Sep101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's actually better if you were to implement UUID in your Laravel Application:

https://medium.com/@steveazz/setting-up-uuids-in-laravel-5-552412db2088

> UUID is short for “universal unique identifier” which is a set of 36 characters, containing letters and numbers. Each set should be unique, with there only being a chance for repetition each 100 years, you can read more about it and check out some cool statistics here and here.

Also don't put a value on your input - generate the unique ID server side (either in your controller/model).

If you leave the unique value in the input, there's nothing stopping users from actually changing that value.

Comment: 'Each set should be unique, with there only being a chance for repetition each 100 years', This sounds convincing. Thank you mate, for the answer.

Comment: I think i think we have got some confusion here, 
Long user id such as ”id”: “b14e5c00-e899–11e5–9c37-df062687ba4f”, is very difficult to provide to users as their user id. I want to make it short and sweet too,

Comment: In that case wouldn't it be easier just to check if the user exists (either by email/some other identifier) once they submit ?

Comment: Yes, i think this will be working for my case : 
http://phppot.com/jquery/live-username-availability-check-using-php-and-jquery-ajax/